# error while running sbt assembly : sbt deduplication error

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

I am facing the exact issue as described in the below post and the suggested answer is not helping.
[sbt-assembly: deduplication found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144484/sbt-assembly-deduplication-found-error/25147568#25147568)

```
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.transaction\orbits\javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.servlet\orbits\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.mail.glassfish\orbits\javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.activation\orbits\javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] Total time: 14 s, completed Sep 9, 2014 5:21:01 PM
```

my build.sbt file contains

```
name := "Simple"

version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.3"
)

//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.0.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "0.4.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ("org.apache.spark"%%"spark-core"%"1.0.2").
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet").
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction").
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail").
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.activation").
    exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
    exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
    exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
    exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog")
)

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"

    mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
    {
        case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("javax", "transaction", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("javax", "mail", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.first
        case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
        case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
        case "unwanted.txt"     => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => old(x)
        }
    }
```

Any pointers on how to fix the above issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning to run your program from Spark, then I strongly recommend to add all Spark dependencies as `provided` so they will be excluded from assembly task.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"              % "1.0.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming"         % "1.0.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.0.2" % "provided")
```

In the other case, you need to either remove those `jar`s from classpath or to add appropriate lines to `mergeStrategy`, in your case it would be

```
case PathList("META-INF", "ECLIPSEF.RSA") => MergeStrategy.first
```

If you still wish to deal with Spark's dependencies hell, [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin should help. Also note that other Spark dependencies, like `spark-streaming` and `spark-streaming-twitter` probably needs `exclude` directive too.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this " If you are planning to run your program from Spark, then I strongly recommend to add all Spark dependencies as provided." How do i add them?

Comment: @Siva It means that in case when Spark is running, these jars are already available when you deploying your job and there's no need to ship them with application. See my updated answer.

Comment: And when i tried to add the above merge strategy, it resulted on one more error, [error] C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\cache\com.esotericsoftware.kryo\kryo\bundles\kryo-2.21.jar:com/esotericsoftware/minlog/Log$Logger.class
error] C:\Users\xxx\.ivy2\cache\com.esotericsoftware.minlog\minlog\jars\minlog-1.2.jar:com/esotericsoftware/minlog/Log$Logger.class

Comment: Problem with this is it goes against the whole point of assembly ... that is to build a fat jar where worrying about classpath is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to get the annoying "deduplicate" messages to go away I didn't bother with the exclude stuff, it didn't seem to help with me.  I copied and pasted the `defaultMergeStrategy` from the sbt code and just changed the line where it says `deduplicate` to `first`. I also had to add a catch all at the end to insist upon `first` too.  To be honest I have no idea what this means, or why it makes the annoying messages go away ... I don't have time to get a Phd in sbt, I want my code to just build!! So the merge strat becomes:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) ((old) => {
  case x if Assembly.isConfigFile(x) =>
    MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if Assembly.isReadme(ps.last) || Assembly.isLicenseFile(ps.last) =>
    MergeStrategy.rename
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps @ (x :: xs) if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa") =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "plexus" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case ("spring.schemas" :: Nil) | ("spring.handlers" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first // Changed deduplicate to first
    }
  case PathList(_*) => MergeStrategy.first // added this line
})
```

Comment: Did this work? I tried it and the fat jar was suspiciously small.