# Standalone Spark application with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm working on a spark application and have already done the logic, yet I have little-to-none experience with creating a standalone application.

I have to have a runnable jar, yet when I try to run scala path/to/my/jar I get

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
```

This is my build.sbt

```
name := "Spark_Phase2"

version := "0.1"

organization := "bartosz.spark"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies+= "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies+= "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
```

From what I have seen there is something wrong with dependencies but I could not figure excatly what I have to do to make it runnable.

What puzzles me even more is that `sbt run` does runs the code fine. So it would be nice if someone could write a step-by-step solution to this :)

And one more thing, I have to take a couple command-line parameters with flags and I have never done it before, does anyone have any good docs/tutorial on this?

Comment: You'll either need a fat jar or make sure that Spark dependencies are available on the classpath. That being said Spark doesn't support running applications outside `spark-submit` (it usually works, but it is not guaranteed to work).

Comment: Any instructions on how to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: I have added the sbt-assembly plugin but I did not help much. I get the same error when I try to run the jar-file.

Had to add
`assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}`

to build.sbt in order to not get deduplication error (solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144484/sbt-assembly-deduplication-found-error ).
Any ide what may be wrong?

Comment: You need to build a fat jar first using 'sbt assembly' command and use this jar when running java, not the jar you created initially.

Comment: I'm trying now to go with an `assemblyMergeStrategy`yet I get an deduplicate error (when I try to run `sbt assembly`) on org.apache.arrow. I tired to use `case PathList("org","apache",xs @ _*) =>MergeStrategy.last`but that did not help.

Comment: As for spark-sumbit, unfortunately the the lecturers want a stand alone application that they may run from command-line with parameters. So I can't use spark-submit.