# Logback Logging with Scala and Sbt in spark-submmit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, assembly, logging, sbt

I'm trying to generate a fat-jar (with sbt assembly) and then send it to spark using spark-submit and have my application use my logback logging appenders and encoders.

I have tried what is stated in: [Configuring Apache Spark Logging with Scala and logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356887/configuring-apache-spark-logging-with-scala-and-logback)  and also in [Separating application logs in Logback from Spark Logs in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126107/separating-application-logs-in-logback-from-spark-logs-in-log4j/45480145#45480145)

but with no success. Either the far jar fails due to some deduplicate errors or the application does not start due to some error in the sparkContext creation.

My build.sbt

```scala
libraryDependencies += Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))
  , "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion  excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))
  , "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion  excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))
  , "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion  excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))
  , "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.0"  excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))


  , "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
  , "io.minio" % "minio" % "6.0.11" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization= "com.google.code.findbugs", name= "annotations"))
  , "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2"
  , "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.3.2"
  , "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.4.1.jre8"
  , "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.25"
)


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {

  case PathList("com",   "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "squareup", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "sun", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "thoughtworks", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-beanutils", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-cli", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-collections", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-io", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("io",    "netty", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "xml", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "codehaus", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "glassfish", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "fusesource", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "mortbay", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "tukaani", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "twitter", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "objenesis", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("xerces", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("xmlenc", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "git.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.xml" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "parquet.thrift" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "codegen/config.fmpp" => MergeStrategy.last


  // Needed only to sbt assembly non provided spark-streaming-kafka-0-10
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  // Needed only to sbt assembly etcd coming with libraries
  case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  // Needed only to sbt assembly mastria-etcd4s coming with libraries
  case PathList("scala","collection","mutable", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("scala","collection","mutable", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("scala","util", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("library.properties", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("logback.xml",xs @ _ *) => MergeStrategy.last
  case x => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
  //case PathList("MANIFEST.MF",xs @ _ *) => MergeStrategy.first
 // case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {

  case PathList("com",   "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "squareup", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "sun", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "thoughtworks", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-beanutils", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-cli", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-collections", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("commons-io", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("io",    "netty", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "xml", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "codehaus", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "glassfish", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "fusesource", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "mortbay", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "tukaani", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com",   "twitter", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org",   "objenesis", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("xerces", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("xmlenc", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "git.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.xml" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "parquet.thrift" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "codegen/config.fmpp" => MergeStrategy.last


  // Needed only to sbt assembly non provided spark-streaming-kafka-0-10
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  // Needed only to sbt assembly etcd coming with libraries
  case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  // Needed only to sbt assembly mastria-etcd4s coming with libraries
  case PathList("scala","collection","mutable", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("scala","collection","mutable", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("scala","util", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("library.properties", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("logback.xml",xs @ _ *) => MergeStrategy.last
  case x => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
  //case PathList("MANIFEST.MF",xs @ _ *) => MergeStrategy.first
 // case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

When I use typesafe LazyLogging class the process fails no matter the combination of arguemtns I try to use.

I would like to see a full build.sbt example to maybe find my mistake.

Comment: I had once a similar problem, maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55807112/1612432